# What's the advantage of using LINQ when I query a database with EF6?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I have been using EF6 for my application and will soon move to 6.1. Normally all my EF is handled with LINQ like this:

```
        var exams = _examsRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Where(q => q.SubjectId == subjectId)
            .Include(q => q.Tests)
            .ToList();
```

However I just had a suggestion to use this for a particular query:

```
        var exams1 = (from ex in DbContext.Exams
                     join t in DbContext.Tests on ex.ExamId equals t.ExamId
                     join ut in DbContext.UserTests on t.TestId equals ut.TestId
                     where ut.UserId == "123"
                     select new { ex, t, ut }).ToList();
```

Can someone tell me what are the advantages of using the second way. I realize one advantage is that it seems I can do things which cannot be done the first way (nobody has yet been able to code the what's needed in the second example the first way. What if any are the other advantages?  Are they the only two recommended ways I could use EF to query a SQL Server 2012 database.

I would like to learn more about how to code the second way. Does anyone know of some good links which explain this?

Comment: Both of these forms are LINQ, the former is just using the expression language syntax. As far as I know, there is no functional difference between the two and at first sight that second example shouldn't be hard to convert to the former.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - I opened a question about that and nobody has been able to do it / get it working. I will start a bounty soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[method versus query based syntax with Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Method based is more comprehensive than query based.
You can mix them a little. 
Query can be more readable especially around Joins.